# Why `switch(null)` is a compile error but `switch(str)` is fine with str being `static final String str = null;`?

Tags: java, null, switch-statement, constants, compile-time-constant

While `switch(null)` is a compile error but `switch(str)` is fine (`str` being `static final String str = null;`).

Isn't `static final String str = null;`  a compile-time constant which shall be substituted into `switch(str)` at compile time and thus be equivalent to `switch(null)`?

```
switch (null) {  // compile Error immediately!

}
```

BUT:

```
public class Test {

    // compile-time constant?
    static final String s4 = null; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        switch (s4) {  // compiles fine! NPE at runtime

        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I suppose `static final String str = null;` *IS NOT a compile-time constant, because only `static final String str = 'string literal'` is a compile-time constant*, which explains example above (s4).

Comment: Try `switch ((String)null)` - it's just a matter of type.

Comment: The error I get is quite explanatory "_Cannot switch on a value of type null. Only convertible int values, strings or enum variables are permitted_" what is the error your compiler gave ? It is always nice to include it in the question.

Comment: Following the same logic you should expect compile time errors on any operation you would perform on `str`, eg: `str.concat("");`

Answer (score 7):

From the error message:

> Incompatible types. Found 'null', required: 'char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Integer, String, or an enum'

You can see that `null` is inferred to nothing, it's not even an `Object`, it **is** simply the "null type", and not a `String` (or any other valid switchable type).

So for it to compile you'd need to cast it to `String` (or one of the other valid types).

```
switch((String) null) {
```

Which then throws a `RuntimeException` when you try to execute it.

This behaviour is not only applicable to `switch` it is in fact the same as when you do this:

```
null.isEmpty()
```

How should java know that you want to invoke `String#isEmpty()`? You could aswell mean `Collection#isEmpty()`. Or any other `isEmpty()` method. The same goes for the `switch`-example, java simply doesn't know which type you mean.

Answer (score 3):

From [Oracle's doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

> Unlike if-then and if-then-else statements, the switch statement can
>   have a number of possible execution paths. A switch works with the
>   byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with
>   enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a
>   few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character,
>   Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings).

Hence `switch(null)` is invalid because you can't switch on any value (`null` could be a null `Banana` object which is not supported)